# Modifying values in a radar chart.js based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, input, chart.js, radar-chart

I have a chart.js radar map and I also have some input fields. I want to change values (points) in the graph based on user input. I prefer to update the chart as the user is typing the value.

But the alternative is to update the chart by clicking the "update" button.

What's the best way to do update the graph as the user is typing the input.

And what's the best way to do update the graph by clicking on the "update" buttons?

You can check my code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/qsfvy8ze/2/

Here is also the important parts of my code:

```
      <table id="editable_table" class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class='th' id=0>Skill</th>
            <th class='th' id=1>Departmental Average</th>
            <th class='th' id=2>Employee</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
     <tbody id="tableData">
        <tr>
            <td>
            Skill 1
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="depAverage1" placeholder="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="employee1" placeholder="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <tr>
            <td>
            Skill 7
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="depAverage7" placeholder="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="employee7" placeholder="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">SAVE</button>
    </div>
    <div class=col-md-5>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>


<script>
var depAverage1 = document.getElementById("depAverage1").value;
.
.
.
var depAverage7 = document.getElementById("depAverage7").value;


var employee1 = document.getElementById("depAverage1").value;
.
.
.
var employee7 = document.getElementById("depAverage7").value;

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            .
            .
            .
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting onChange event listeners to each input and then targeting the value of the input?

```
<input id='user-input' onchange='checkInput()' />

checkInput = () => {
    let input = document.getElementById('user-input').value;

    updateChart(input);
}
```

I feel like something along these lines will work. Look into the event listeners that monitor user input.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp